# How to Determine XML layout for Fragments in Tabs?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Okay, So I just started Android development (I am average at VB.Net, so I understand basic code even if its not in VB). I've made a couple play around apps which used Text-To-Speech, Async Tasks and Reading/Writing files. However, I now wish to make a tabbed Android app.

I started the project in Eclipse Juno and filled in all the details. I then selected (For navigation) the `Tabs/Swipe` layout. I now have the default code for that layout type (Link to Tabs on developer.android.com - http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html).

I understand mostly what the default code is doing. The only problem I am having, is determining the individual layout of my `Tabs`. I wish to have 2 `Tabs`, 1 in which the user selects an option, and the other, in which an image is shown depending on the selection in `Tab 1`.

So the question is: How do I create a `.xml` file in `Layout` to determine what is shown on the `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in XML the answer is simple, it can't be done just with XML, you must create a class that's implementing a **ActionBar.TabListener**.

Than you can override the **onTabSelected** method in which you can exchange the content. 
A proper solution would be: 
Use a LinearLayout as root container, and implement two Fragments for each of your Tabs (there you can design an individual XML-layout). Now you can add one fragment initially to the root-container and implement the exchange of the layouts inside the onTabSelected method and you are done.